# Javascript setTimeout into two loops

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

I try since few days to create an javascript patern.

I parse an multidimentionnal array with "an for loop" that contain x and y positions as this :

```
array[1][x]
array[1][y]

array[2][x]
array[2][y]

ect...
```

i don't know the length the user push x and y numbers in an array and at the end an function is activated then **length of the array is fixed**. every seconds i want to increase or decrease x and y for one number at the end of the array.length i want to rebegin to parse the array, the parsing function stop when array[1][x] == stopX &&  array[1][y] == stopY.

i tested different approachs I have bug and infinite loops.

```
// i know stopX and stopY they are numbers and never change.
    var stopX = 25; 
    var stopy = 49;
//i wish an condition to stop the script as this :
    while( array[i][x] != stopX && array[i][y] != stopY ){

    for( i = 1 ; i < array.length; i++ ){
    (function(){
    var j = i;
       setTimeout( function(){ 
//here differents "if( ){" to increase or decrease array[i][x] and array[i][y];
          array[i][x] += 1;
          array[i][y] += 1;
        }, j*1000);
       }
   }
}
```

Do i need "while number" as this "w*j*1000" i don't grasp this concept , i don't understand completely the utility of the closure i but that worked better, i think i need an second closure but where and how i can set up this?

Comment: so every 1 second what are you looking to achieve from the function (sorry the writing is confusing) you are advancing 1 step into the array, and adding 1 to the x and y in the array every second, what if the array does not have this length

Comment: Shouldn't you use `j` inside the closure? The only occasion you use `j`, it has the same value as `i`.

Comment: Yes i advancing 1step per second in the array until the end of the array, if a array[1][x] == stopX && array[1][y] == stopY the loop stop. if array[1][x] !== stopX && !array[1][y] == stopY the loop to parse the array rebeginning to add 1 until to match the number of stepX.

Answer (score 0):

In final i replacef "while loop" by setinterval+setTimeout+clearInterval.